# HTC One model c525c, errors downloading from Play Store (491, 905, 915, and insufficient space)

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, htc-one

Earlier this month I thought I had a virus so I factory reset my phone, which is rooted. I have been trying to reinstall my games, over 40 of them. Only have 6 of them now and my phone keeps telling me I have insufficient space, with all the apps and games that I can move to my 16 gig SD card, which only has less than one gig used on it.

I used to always get error 491 before factory reset. I have been getting 915 and most recently, 905. And the ones that do download to 100% lockup at 100% and won't open. Plus I can't even update. Please help me fix, especially the 915 latest error.

Comment: Have you seen our [google-play-store tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) with its list of error messages? There's a link for at least two of yours: [Downloading from Play Store gives error 491](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/83432/16575) and [Can't I install or update Apps from Play Store: Error 905 . How to fix?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25918/16575) As for the space issue, please take a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info).

Answer (score 0):

Try to download SD maid in your device clear your phone cache and reebot you device i think that should work, if works don't forget to download anti virus in your device like avira..

Comment: What does an anti-virus have to do with that?